# Visual Studio Error Else and Expression Expected?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote some code and an getting two errors:

1. `'Else' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or 'ElseIf'.`
2. `Expression expected.`

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class FormLogin
    Dim CMD As New OdbcCommand
    Dim RD As OdbcDataReader

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Data Login Belum Lengkap!")
        Exit Sub
        Else
        Call Koneksi()
        CMD = New OdbcCommand("Select * From tbl_admin where kode_admin=" & TextBox1.Text & "and password_admin=" & TextBox2.Text &, Conn)
        RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
        RD.Read()
        If RD.HasRows Then
            Me.Close()
            FormMenuUtama.Show()
            FormMenuUtama.LoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
            FormMenuUtama.LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            FormMenuUtama.MasterToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            FormMenuUtama.TransaksiToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            FormMenuUtama.LaporanToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Kode Admin atau Password Salah")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.MaxLength = 6
        TextBox2.PasswordChar = "*"
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Button1_Click` has two `If`s but only one `EndIf`...

Comment: It looks like I could defeat your password check by entering something like `'' OR 1=1` in TextBox2. You should investigate using SQL parameters to pass the values. Also, you have forgotten to .Close() the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Do not put code after `Then` in the `If` statement . It becomes one line

So:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
MsgBox("Data Login Belum Lengkap!")
...
```

instead of

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Data Login Belum Lengkap!")
...
```

**2)** There is an extra `&`

So:

```
CMD = New OdbcCommand("Select * From tbl_admin where kode_admin=" & TextBox1.Text & "and password_admin=" & TextBox2.Text , Conn)
```

instead of

```
CMD = New OdbcCommand("Select * From tbl_admin where kode_admin=" & TextBox1.Text & "and password_admin=" & TextBox2.Text &, Conn)
```

Comment: also queries must use parameters for better security ,you could also add that too in your post..rest all seems fine

Comment: OP is also missing opening and closing `'` on each value.

Answer (score -1):

Add another End If before End Sub.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Data Login Belum Lengkap!")
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call Koneksi()
    CMD = New OdbcCommand("Select * From tbl_admin where kode_admin=" & TextBox1.Text & "and password_admin=" & TextBox2.Text &, Conn)
    RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
    RD.Read()
    If RD.HasRows Then
        Me.Close()
        FormMenuUtama.Show()
        FormMenuUtama.LoginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        FormMenuUtama.LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        FormMenuUtama.MasterToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        FormMenuUtama.TransaksiToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        FormMenuUtama.LaporanToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
    Else
        MsgBox("Kode Admin atau Password Salah")
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```